# How to compare value of HTML input in-line

Tags: html, css, comparison

I'd like an input which has a 'highlight' class if value != defaultValue.
Due to the library I am using, I can't reliably use names or onChange events. (If needed, I can do it, but it'll be a pain to set up).
Currently it looks like:

```
<td><input type="number" className={(this.value !== this.defaultValue ? 'highlight' : '')} defaultValue={1}/></td>
```

I get an error when trying to use 'this.value' or 'this.defaultValue' because the context for 'this' refers to the page, not the element.
Is there an in-line way I can get this value for comparison?

Answer (score 0):

As best as I could find, there's no way to do this.
The solution I came up with was,

```
<td><input id={table.ID.toString()} type="number" onChange={() => highlightElement(table.ID.toString()} defaultValue={table.defaultValue}/> </td>
```

And defined highlightElement() as:

```
function highlightElement(id:string){
     const element = document.getElementById(id);
     element.style.backgroundColor = "#FDFF47";
}
```

...There's probably a way I could also input the intended default value as a function parameter and get the current value of the input, compare the two, and if matched DON'T highlight it, else apply the style. But this suits what I currently need.